# Set file metadata attribute values

Tags: macos, bash, filesystem, metadata

I'm trying to set the values of some file metadata attributes in OS X Yosemite - `kMDItemDateAdded` and `kMDItemLastUsedDate` - the values of which can be shown using `mdls <filename>`.  I'm trying to set their values using `xattr`.

I've tried this:

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDateAdded "2001-01-01 12:34:56 +0000" some_file.txt
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate "2001-01-01 12:34:56 +0000" some_file.txt
```

I've tried this:

```
xattr -w kMDItemDateAdded "2011-01-01 12:34:56 +0000" some_file.txt
xattr -w kMDItemLastUsedDate "2011-01-01 12:34:56 +0000" some_file.txt
```

...but have had no success.  `xattr` reports no errors, but the file metadata attribute values are left unchanged.

Do you know if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if it is, where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you try `xattr -l some_file.txt` to look at the values after changing them? And no, I don't have an explanation for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @patrix.  I've tried ```xattr -l some_file.txt```, **before and after** executing the four commands listed in my question above.  Before executing the commands, the attributes ```com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDateAdded```, ```com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate```, ```kMDItemDateAdded```, ```kMDItemLastUsedDate``` aren't listed.  After executing the commands, they are.

Comment: However - the values of ```kMDItemDateAdded``` and ```kMDItemLastUsedDate```, shown using ```mdls <filename>```, are unchanged.  Could it be, that the four commands listed in my question above create _new_ attributes (shown using ```xattr -l some_file.txt```), and that ```mdls <filename>``` gets its attribute values from elsewhere?

Comment: That was my first thought as well, didn't research the topic though.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this question as well, and it appears that the "Data Added" attribute (`kMDItemDateAdded`) can be queried from `mdls` (but not `xattr`), but cannot be set. There is no option for it in the [`setattrlist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setattrlist.2.html) function. The comments on [this SO question](http://astronomyontap.org) go into a little (but not much) more detail. The "Date Added" value appears to be derived from some other seemingly inaccessible metadata value, not stored as an extended attribute.

I would guess the same applies for the "Last Used" date.